# List of distinct values using Linq (Linq, C#)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, linq, distinct

I have method which return number of Distinct "AutoName".

```
public int getNumberAutoNameDistinct()
{
    testViewClassDataContext tv = new testViewClassDataContext();
    int q2 = tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct().Count();

    return q2;
}
```

How to return List of Distinct AutoNames?

Comment: remove `.Count()` and try something on your own before asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the return type of the method [Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) you see that it returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>`. You are basically almost there. You could just skip the `Count` part and return the `IEnumerable<TSource>`. But if you really want to have a List you should use the [ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
List<string> list = tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct().ToList();
```

You whole method would look like this:

```
public List<string> getNumberAutoNameDistinct()
{
    testViewClassDataContext tv = new testViewClassDataContext();
    return tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well if you just simply remove count() you will get what you want.

```
var autoNames = tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct().ToList();
```

**EDIT 1**

your function is returning integer value, so if you want to do something with the names and then return number of unique AutoNames its better if you try this.

```
public int getNumberAutoNameDistinct()
{
    testViewClassDataContext tv = new testViewClassDataContext();
    var autoNames = tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct().ToList();

    // do something with autoNames

    return autoNames.Count();
    }
```

Comment: i have added toList()

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
var _list = tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` query here. It will return you full object.

```
public List<ObjectType> GetDistinctName()
{
  var autoNames = tv.test_views.
      .GroupBy(p => p.AutoName)
      .Select(g => g.First())
      .ToList();
  return autoNames;
}
```

Replace **ObjectType** with your **ClassName**.

Comment: hi, can you please put me a  full method?

Comment: I have accepted @MongZhu answer, but anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*You must use only Distinct ,the function you are using is to count the Distinct* .

Try following code

```
testViewClassDataContext tv = new testViewClassDataContext();
int q2 = tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the mentioned code `tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct()`

regards,
Vinu